# Indesign - Why does the stroke imported from Photoshop (left) look fine while ID's stroke (right) looks jagged and horrible?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-indesign, stroke

I tried changing my Display Performance, and also exported a PDF to make sure it rendered that way and sure enough it does.

Same font, same stroke, two Adobe apps with wildly different results. Can't say I'm surprised.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Click "Stroke" and adjust the Join to Round.

Comment: Note that you can [accept your own answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer).